# How to correctly reset time

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using a bag in a loop because it is just convenient to keep the bag running and testing different algorithms.
The problem is that once the bag starts from the beginning, my nodes using tf start printing out a lot of warnings about TF_OLD_DATA. To solve this, an empty message should be published to /reset_time.

I tried pushing the reset button in RVIZ but nothing happens and for example amcl complains about old tf data. Is there any solution to that problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215734/how-to-correctly-reset-time/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the --clock parameter in rosbag (e.g rosbag play --clock wg-cafe.bag). This way the TF buffer clears automatically on negative time.

See this as well:
http://answers.ros.org/question/206748/tf_old_data-ignoring-data-from-the-past-for-frame-openni_depth_optical_frame/

---

Originally posted by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) with karma: 257 on 2016-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dhagash Desai](https://answers.ros.org/users/26869/dhagash-desai/) on 2016-10-29**:
i am running this command only and nothing happens instead.i start gmapping slam_gmapping in one termonal and in other i start the rosbag play --clock file.bag. And nothing happen in the gmapping terminal, And error comes 100% messages dropped. I am using to record bag file of tf and scan in p3dx.